# How to get stats from a scrapy run?

Tags: python, mysql, web-scraping, scrapy

I am running the scrapy spider from external file as per the example in scrapy docs. I want to grab the stats provided by the Core API and store it to mysql table after the crawl is finished.

```
from twisted.internet import reactor
from scrapy.crawler import Crawler
from scrapy import log, signals
from test.spiders.myspider import *
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings
from test.pipelines import MySQLStorePipeline
import datetime

spider = MySpider()


def run_spider(spider):        
    settings = get_project_settings()
    crawler = Crawler(settings)
    crawler.signals.connect(reactor.stop, signal=signals.spider_closed)
    crawler.configure()
    crawler.crawl(spider)
    crawler.start()
    log.start()
    reactor.run()
    mysql_insert = MySQLStorePipeline()
        mysql_insert.cursor.execute(
            'insert into crawler_stats(sites_id, start_time,end_time,page_scraped,finish_reason) 
              values(%s,%s,%s, %s,%s)',
                  (1,datetime.datetime.now(),datetime.datetime.now(),100,'test'))

    mysql_insert.conn.commit()

run_spider(spider)
```

How can I get the values of stats like start_time, end_time, pages_scraped, finish_reason in the above code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Get them from the [`crawler.stats` collector](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/api.html#scrapy.crawler.Crawler.stats):

```
stats = crawler.stats.get_stats()
```

Example code (collecting stats in the `spider_closed` signal handler):

```
def callback(spider, reason):
    stats = spider.crawler.stats.get_stats()  # stats is a dictionary

    # write stats to the database here

    reactor.stop()


def run_spider(spider):        
    settings = get_project_settings()
    crawler = Crawler(settings)
    crawler.signals.connect(callback, signal=signals.spider_closed)
    crawler.configure()
    crawler.crawl(spider)
    crawler.start()
    log.start()
    reactor.run()


run_spider(spider)
```

Comment: I am not getting finish_time and finish_reason from the stats.

Comment: @Ngeunpo yeah, this is because [`finish_time` and `finish_reason` are also set in the same signal handler](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/e748ca50ca3e83ac703e02538a27236fedd53a7d/scrapy/contrib/corestats.py#L27-L28). We need to handle promises and use `deferred` here I think. Could you make a separate question? I think this is something that can be useful for others and really is suitable for a separate thread. I'll take a look more closely then. Thanks!

Comment: I got the logic but I am not sure about separate question!!