# How to get stats of mutliple scraping runs in scrapy?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I couldn't get the below StackOverflow answer work for me as I am running multiple spiders and rely on `CrawlerProcess` instead of `Crawler`.

[How to get stats from a scrapy run?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27739380/how-to-get-stats-from-a-scrapy-run)

I would like to access the stats of both runs with something like `get_stats()`, but couldn't figure out which object would have a `get_stats()` attribute. Any help very much appreciated.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "quotes"

    def parse(self, response):
        yield {
             'name': response.css('small.author::text').extract_first()
        }

class QuotesSpider1(QuotesSpider):
    name = "quotes1"
    start_urls = ['http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/1/']

class QuotesSpider2(QuotesSpider):
    name = "quotes2"
    start_urls = ['http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/2/']

if __name__ == "__main__":
    process = CrawlerProcess({
        'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)',
        'FEED_FORMAT': 'jsonlines',
        'FEED_URI': 'result.jl',
    })
    process.crawl(QuotesSpider1)
    process.crawl(QuotesSpider2)
    process.start()
```

Comment: You want to get them through telnet console...right?

Comment: I am not sure what the telnet console is. I just want to add a line of code to the above script to get the stats and print them. It is in fact printed automatically, but when I have hundreds of scrapes, the stats of the first spider get lost in all the output, so would just like to print it again once the code has run.